# Mongo query to ignore extreme values?

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am trying drawing chart using MongoDB data, showing the minimum (floor) price of all transactions over a few days (green color line in the attached).

One problem is that, a few extreme transactions that sold at ridiculously low prices, made the sales floor green line going to zero.

If I filter the data using a query like this:

```
{"price": {$gte: 0.5}}
```

Green line will look more realistic:

[image]

But this only works because I know this particular chart the price should be around 10 to 20 so anything less than 0.5 is considered extreme.

In reality, I do not know what is the prices being feed into the chart, the price could be between 10 to 20, or between 0.01 to 0.02. So I cannot hard code 0.5.

Is there any MondoDB tricks, or special operators, or standard practise to filter away the extreme/outlier values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$bucketAuto](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) to group your data by value.

In my case, I have 10 docs.

I separate them in 5 of 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%.

Then I remove the first 20% and the last 20%.

So the documents only keep the 60% in the middle.

Some how it ignore extreme values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $bucketAuto: {
      groupBy: "$price",
      buckets: 5,
      output: {
        docs: {
          $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 1
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.max": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 1
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$docs"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CXEpcsFmbS8)

Comment: I have one more question, which I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949876/mongodb-query-remove-bottom-10-extreme-values-for-each-specific-type-of-data