# MongoDB query remove bottom 10% extreme values for each specific type of data

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a MongoDB storing transaction prices of a few products like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "product": "A",
    "price": NumberDecimal("1.00")
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "product": "A",
    "price": NumberDecimal("20.00")
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "product": "A",
    "price": NumberDecimal("30.00")
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "product": "B",
    "price": NumberDecimal("10.00")
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "product": "B",
    "price": NumberDecimal("200.00")
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "product": "B",
    "price": NumberDecimal("300.00")
  }
]
```

I want to remove bottom 10% of the extreme transaction prices, I do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $bucketAuto: {
      groupBy: "$price",
      buckets: 10,
      output: {
        docs: {
          $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 1
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$docs"
  }
])
```

The outcome is like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "price": NumberDecimal("10.00"),
    "product": "B"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "price": NumberDecimal("20.00"),
    "product": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "price": NumberDecimal("30.00"),
    "product": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "price": NumberDecimal("200.00"),
    "product": "B"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "price": NumberDecimal("300.00"),
    "product": "B"
  }
]
```

The extreme transaction price 1.00 is removed. But I actually want the extreme 10% prices for each product to be removed, so that price 1.00 of product A is removed, and price 10.00 for product B is also removed. Expected result should be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "price": NumberDecimal("20.00"),
    "product": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "price": NumberDecimal("30.00"),
    "product": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "price": NumberDecimal("200.00"),
    "product": "B"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "price": NumberDecimal("300.00"),
    "product": "B"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this? I have something very close but it is hard coding the product names in the query, which is very wrong:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/ur3Qmr2VJKb

Comment: I'm still thinking if there is a better way than hard coding.

Comment: Maybe you can only make it in application level. First `find` all `product`. Second Make multiple `$bucketAuto` In `$facet` by using `JS` or `Java`. So it would be dynamic. I don't think I can make it in only one query.

Comment: Ok noted thanks!